# Getting 403 Error while appending logs in Google sheet (JAVA)

Tags: java, google-sheets-api, google-api-java-client

I am trying to append Logs from java into the Google Sheet but I am getting `403` error

Dummy Code:

```
private static void appendCurrentRunLog(String spreadSheetId, Sheets service,String logId)
    {
        try{
            String logSheetRange=logId+".log!A1:Z";
            for(int k=0;k<logList.size();k++){
                ValueRange appendbody = new ValueRange().setValues(
                        Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(logList.get(k))));
                service.spreadsheets().values()
                        .append(spreadSheetId, logSheetRange, appendbody)
                        .setValueInputOption("user_entered")
                        .setInsertDataOption("insert_rows")
                        .setIncludeValuesInResponse(true)
                        .execute();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            mLogger.info("Failed while inserting logs"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
  "status" : "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

where should I use batchUpdate() and how?
Any other solution?
Please suggest!!

Comment: can you show the error in the log that you have?

Comment: 403 indicates a permissions issue -- check your creds and how you're using them. Do you have write permissions on the sheet?

Comment: error added @MarcosEchagüe

Comment: yes @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: Maybe you're doing some mistake when building your credentials for your Sheets Object, refer to this example https://github.com/googleworkspace/java-samples/blob/master/sheets/quickstart/src/main/java/SheetsQuickstart.java

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the error points out to authentication scope. Try these following items:

1. Delete credentials that are in `/Users/<username>/.credentials`.
2. You might be using a wrong scope. Use `SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS` instead if you are modifying the file. See the list of scopes [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/java/latest/com/google/api/services/sheets/v4/SheetsScopes.html).

Also, refer this [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/java) as a guide.